# Numpy calculate values in middle

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have numpy array which represents my x-axis, ex.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to get values in the middle of two adjacent element, so my example array should turn into

```
x_interp = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

Is there a fast and convinient way to do this using python/numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a numpy array, just slice with a shift:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

x_interp = (x[1:]+x[:-1])/2
```

Output: `array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])`

An alternative (and also more generic approach to get the mean of every `N` items) would be to use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 2
x_interp = swv(x, N).mean(axis=1)
```